# How do I restrict a text input to numbers only but allow numbers from a 10 key?

Tags: jquery, regex, format

I am confused why I am not able to use the 10 key to input numbers.

The following example auto fills the "/".  I tried a few different ways to adjust the regex on it, but when I do, I can't backspace or delete anything past the last "/".  (01/01/2000 ... 01/01/ <- won't let me delete past this).

```
       $('#date').keydown(function (e) {
            var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
            $date = $(this);

            if (key !== 8) {
                var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9\t/]");
                var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
                if (!regex.test(key)) {
                   event.preventDefault();
                   return false;
                }

                if ($date.val().length === 0) {
                    $date.val($date.val() + '');
                }
                if ($date.val().length === 2) {
                    $date.val($date.val() + '/');
                }
                if ($date.val().length === 5) {
                    $date.val($date.val() + '/');
                }
            }
        });
```

Please help me find a way where it continues to auto-format the  "/" as it does now but restricts to numbers only (except the required "/") and allows me to use the 10 key numbers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want allow only number and ignore any key :
use this code in JavaScript tag:

```
 $('*[data-validation="digit"]').keydown(function (e) {
                if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
                        (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
                        (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40)) {
                    return;
                }
                if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });
```

and any input that you want apply this role add this attribute :

```
data-validation="digit"
```

for example :

```
<input data-validation="digit" />
```

I recommend you Use  a Masked Input plugin eg:
[Masked Input plugin for jQuery](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/#demo)

for example for date :

```
 $("#date").mask("99/99/9999",{placeholder:"mm/dd/yyyy"});
```

in this plugin you can combination of word and number or any characters

Comment: This works VERY well.  Exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking for backspace properly.
Check your value of 'key'.

I think it should assigned as followed:

```
var key = e.keyCode;
```

Also, why is half of it `e` and later on you have `event`?

```
var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
```

This might also be useful for JS reference:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/

You might also want to use jQuery's `which`. It should work across browsers.

Comment: thank you for your suggestions with with the keyCode, though it still doesn't allow the numbers from the 10-key.  This was one of the 1st examples I was learning about the different event handlers so I actually started off using "event" for everything, but then switched to "e". I probably just got lazy and didn't change all the "event"s .  but it works just the same either way.

Comment: Try a different browser. Also, what is 10?

Comment: The 10-key is the number pad on the right of the keyboard.  The numbers in the row on the top of the keyboard work fine, but when you use the numbers on the number pad, it doesn't work.

Comment: I have tried it in Chrome, IE and Firefox, and Opera and it's the same result